# Why Parenscript is inserting an opening and closing parenthesis in this array creation?

Tags: arrays, common-lisp, parenscript

I am using Paresncript in Common Lisp (SBCL). After invoking an auxiliary function called `(write-input-data)`, the REPL returns a list of strings:

```lisp
CL-USER> (write-input-data)

("2937" "AVpKuU6t_T0" "Joe" "Bush" "random@globo.com" "random@globo.com"
 "WHTpassword" "NIL" "NIL" "1" "2" "-1" "NIL" "NIL" "0" "NIL" "on" "0"
 "b4acdb97-6f1b-4a15-984a-c33c7448032f" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "pt_BR" "NIL"
 "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "yjcIYTMI-bJuQg7nz3hes-qm" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL"
 "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "reg_email_confirmation__"
 "AZnc92iq5Xddjxw0eRPfTh1JH2sQg3gEZ3JDOYp5EQXQZwPSMJ3pAmJnQhH0wtgMb8mq7UxPNiOZIiuxUXpo9ZUwyQZh_Zvh3T_aJcVLBNCZ7Mc7CXfzH4QRKzxfVHXFTI8nR_MlnBWCx0cdAARjUAPGiaQxJJWnkZdS3pQGFiH5ZX83x7r2rFcYI0vmtrRNM50fplxK0ynsMVBYqLBPt-Vqlpf3YmEwGmAoV0FLinVgQ3Yg9WWO0vzLHqrnf3Tq2xVdEHnjHhcsC_RMB_w2CKh9jQlX5llIFVmID62pkCDPHE-aTx7BNsHkcLgaNgTLSWxjCoyEFpKN_Y0xUoSaU6YZAmKu1kaToSreyEWNXR7tyO3-237mOkl72Z3PhtrcI"
 "NIL")
```

Then, I try to convert it to an array filled with strings in javascript syntax:

```lisp
CL-USER> (ps:ps (array (ps:lisp (write-input-data))))

"['2937'('AVpKuU6t_T0', 'Joe', 'Bush', 'random@globo.com', 'random@globo.com', 'WHTpassword', 'NIL', 'NIL', '1', '2', '-1', 'NIL', 'NIL', '0', 'NIL', 'on', '0', 'b4acdb97-6f1b-4a15-984a-c33c7448032f', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'pt_BR', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'yjcIYTMI-bJuQg7nz3hes-qm', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'reg_email_confirmation__', 'AZnc92iq5Xddjxw0eRPfTh1JH2sQg3gEZ3JDOYp5EQXQZwPSMJ3pAmJnQhH0wtgMb8mq7UxPNiOZIiuxUXpo9ZUwyQZh_Zvh3T_aJcVLBNCZ7Mc7CXfzH4QRKzxfVHXFTI8nR_MlnBWCx0cdAARjUAPGiaQxJJWnkZdS3pQGFiH5ZX83x7r2rFcYI0vmtrRNM50fplxK0ynsMVBYqLBPt-Vqlpf3YmEwGmAoV0FLinVgQ3Yg9WWO0vzLHqrnf3Tq2xVdEHnjHhcsC_RMB_w2CKh9jQlX5llIFVmID62pkCDPHE-aTx7BNsHkcLgaNgTLSWxjCoyEFpKN_Y0xUoSaU6YZAmKu1kaToSreyEWNXR7tyO3-237mOkl72Z3PhtrcI', 'NIL')];"
```

The result is **almost** perfect. Unfortunately, there are 2 problems. First, on the beginning, there is a left parenthesis as:

`'2937'('AVpKuU6t_T0'`

And it should be a **comma**:

`'2937' , 'AVpKuU6t_T0'`.

The second error is in the end. There is a right parenthesis:

`'NIL')];"`

It was expected to have nothing, just:
`'NIL' ];"`

Why is this happening? Is there something I could do with parenscript to fix it?

Obviously, I can parse the string and *remove* the parenthesis **a posteriori**, but I guess there is a better approach for this problem.

====
UPDATED

Great user @Barmar, suggested using nothing to fix this. We are almost there. If I do:

```lisp
CL-USER> (ps:ps '("2937" "AVpKuU6t_T0" "Joe" "Bush" "random@globo.com" "random@globo.com"
 "WHTpassword" "NIL" "NIL" "1" "2" "-1" "NIL" "NIL" "0" "NIL" "on" "0"
 "b4acdb97-6f1b-4a15-984a-c33c7448032f" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "pt_BR" "NIL"
 "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "yjcIYTMI-bJuQg7nz3hes-qm" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL"
 "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "NIL" "reg_email_confirmation__"
"AZnc92iq5Xddjxw0eRPfTh1JH2sQg3gEZ3JDOYp5EQXQZwPSMJ3pAmJnQhH0wtgMb8mq7UxPNiOZIiuxUXpo9ZUwyQZh_Zvh3T_aJcVLBNCZ7Mc7CXfzH4QRKzxfVHXFTI8nR_MlnBWCx0cdAARjUAPGiaQxJJWnkZdS3pQGFiH5ZX83x7r2rFcYI0vmtrRNM50fplxK0ynsMVBYqLBPt-Vqlpf3YmEwGmAoV0FLinVgQ3Yg9WWO0vzLHqrnf3Tq2xVdEHnjHhcsC_RMB_w2CKh9jQlX5llIFVmID62pkCDPHE-aTx7BNsHkcLgaNgTLSWxjCoyEFpKN_Y0xUoSaU6YZAmKu1kaToSreyEWNXR7tyO3-237mOkl72Z3PhtrcI"
 "NIL"))
```

I get exactly *what I want*:

```lisp
"['2937', 'AVpKuU6t_T0', 'Joe', 'Bush', 'random@globo.com', 'random@globo.com', 'WHTpassword', 'NIL', 'NIL', '1', '2', '-1', 'NIL', 'NIL', '0', 'NIL', 'on', '0', 'b4acdb97-6f1b-4a15-984a-c33c7448032f', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'pt_BR', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'yjcIYTMI-bJuQg7nz3hes-qm', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'reg_email_confirmation__', 'AZnc92iq5Xddjxw0eRPfTh1JH2sQg3gEZ3JDOYp5EQXQZwPSMJ3pAmJnQhH0wtgMb8mq7UxPNiOZIiuxUXpo9ZUwyQZh_Zvh3T_aJcVLBNCZ7Mc7CXfzH4QRKzxfVHXFTI8nR_MlnBWCx0cdAARjUAPGiaQxJJWnkZdS3pQGFiH5ZX83x7r2rFcYI0vmtrRNM50fplxK0ynsMVBYqLBPt-Vqlpf3YmEwGmAoV0FLinVgQ3Yg9WWO0vzLHqrnf3Tq2xVdEHnjHhcsC_RMB_w2CKh9jQlX5llIFVmID62pkCDPHE-aTx7BNsHkcLgaNgTLSWxjCoyEFpKN_Y0xUoSaU6YZAmKu1kaToSreyEWNXR7tyO3-237mOkl72Z3PhtrcI', 'NIL'];"
```

The only problem is that I inserted the list **directly**. And I need to insert it **indirectly** through a function call of `(write-data)`. If I try just inserting the function call it does not work:

```lisp
CL-USER> (ps:ps  (write-input-data))

"writeInputData();"
```

If I try something similar using the `(ps:lisp` trick, **exactly** the same problem happens with the parenthesis and **no array** is created:

```lisp
> (ps:ps (ps:lisp (write-input-data)))
"'2937'('AVpKuU6t_T0', 'Joe', 'Bush', 'random@globo.com', 'random@globo.com', 'WHTpassword', 'NIL', 'NIL', '1', '2', '-1', 'NIL', 'NIL', '0', 'NIL', 'on', '0', 'b4acdb97-6f1b-4a15-984a-c33c7448032f', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'pt_BR', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'yjcIYTMI-bJuQg7nz3hes-qm', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL', 'reg_email_confirmation__', 'AZnc92iq5Xddjxw0eRPfTh1JH2sQg3gEZ3JDOYp5EQXQZwPSMJ3pAmJnQhH0wtgMb8mq7UxPNiOZIiuxUXpo9ZUwyQZh_Zvh3T_aJcVLBNCZ7Mc7CXfzH4QRKzxfVHXFTI8nR_MlnBWCx0cdAARjUAPGiaQxJJWnkZdS3pQGFiH5ZX83x7r2rFcYI0vmtrRNM50fplxK0ynsMVBYqLBPt-Vqlpf3YmEwGmAoV0FLinVgQ3Yg9WWO0vzLHqrnf3Tq2xVdEHnjHhcsC_RMB_w2CKh9jQlX5llIFVmID62pkCDPHE-aTx7BNsHkcLgaNgTLSWxjCoyEFpKN_Y0xUoSaU6YZAmKu1kaToSreyEWNXR7tyO3-237mOkl72Z3PhtrcI', 'NIL');"
```

Comment: Don't call `array`. It creates an array where each argument is an array element. So it makes the entire list a single element, and it's converting it to a string.

Comment: Why do you say it can't return real JS arrays? The documentation says that `(array 1 2 3)` is translated into `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I am not calling `array` what else should I call?

Comment: Nothing. Lisp lists are automatically converted to JS arrays by Parenscript if I understand the documentation.

Comment: On the second comment, forget what I said then. I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: It's taking `'2937'` as a function to call (with arguments); then creating an array with a single value, which is the result of the `'2937'` function call

Comment: @sabik, thanks. And how do I avoid that from happening?

Comment: is your question about javascript, or about lisp? because [if it's a focussed question](/help/how-to-ask), it's _not_ about both. And from the looks of it, this is purely about something lisp does, not anything related to actual JS.

Comment: thanks, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. I lack deep knowledge about both JS and CL. The domain of the problem is a library supposed to write javascript from lisp. I am not sure if the problem that I am facing has its root on javascript or common lisp. When I wrote it and untill now, I am not 100% sure. Do you suggest removing one of the tags?

Comment: If the problem is with whatever a library for lisp outputs, this is a lisp problem. Not a javascript problem. It's only a javascript problem if there's actual javascript code that you wrote that doesn't work.

Comment: ok, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. Javascript tag removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ps:lisp` form needs to construct the form that `ps:ps` should translate.  So:

```lisp
CL-USER> (ps:ps (ps:lisp (cons 'ps:array (example))))
"[1, 2, 3];"
```